# How to fetch month from date where date column is in varchar datatype. FYI using snowflake tool

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, varchar

How to fetch month from date where date column is in varchar datatype. FYI using snowflake tool.
For example if i want data of june month ? how can i fetch ?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Why are you storing a date as a string, when SQL has wonderful types to support exactly that kind of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`TO_DATE(…)` function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html#syntax) to treat the `VARCHAR` column as a formatted date type, and the [`EXTRACT(…)` function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/extract.html) to retrieve just the month out of the date.

If your date string is formatted in a well-known manner, `TO_DATE`'s automatic parsing (or a [direct cast using the `::` operator](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/cast.html)) will suffice, and you can write your query this way:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE
    EXTRACT(month, TO_DATE(varcharCol)) = 6     -- June of every year
AND EXTRACT(year,  varcharCol::DATE)    = 2020; -- June of 2020 alone
```

Alternatively, if the date is in a non-standard format, [use available formatting options](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-conversion.html#date-and-time-formats-in-conversion-functions) to make `TO_DATE(…)` parse it properly:

```sql
-- Dates of custom format, such as: 'June # 02 # 2020'
SELECT
    EXTRACT(month, TO_DATE(varcharCol, 'MMMM # DD # YYYY')) AS month
FROM table
WHERE
    month = 6;
```

**Note**: You can also swap all `DATE` and `TO_DATE` above with [`TIMESTAMP` and `TO_TIMESTAMP`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_timestamp.html) if the data carries a whole timestamp value within it instead of only a date.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `to_date` in snowflake to convert varchar datatype to date as following

```
select *
from yourTable
where to_date(yourDateColumn, 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= '2020-06-01'
and to_date(yourDateColumn, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= '2020-06-30'
```

Comment: `'2020-06-01'` is a string. `date '2020-06-01'` would be the date literal you are looking for. Then, you should never call  `TO_DATE` without a format. Don't have your DBMS guess whether ' 01/02/2020' is February 1 or January 2. When storing dates as strings you should know the format, so tell the DBMS what format it is.

Comment: That's better. Now precede your string literals with the key word `date` to make these date literals. Your strings are unambiguous and it's easy for the DBMS to convert your strings to dates, but on one hand this is still unnecessary work and on the other hand a human reader might wonder why you are dealing with a date on the left and a string on the right. (It had me confused for a moment, too.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't store dates as strings. But you probably know that.

If you do store dates as strings, you store them all in one particular format, say, 'mm/dd/yyyy'. So, use a `substring` function to get the month digits.

For `'mm/dd/yyyy'`:

```
where substring(date_string, 1, 2) = '06'
```

For `'yyyy-mm-dd'`:

```
where substring(date_string, 9, 2) = '06'
```

In many situations you can also use `LIKE`:

For `'mm/dd/yyyy'`:

```
where date_string like '06%'
```

For `'yyyy-mm-dd'`:

```
where date_string like '%-06-%'
```